# How to call method defined in a mongoose schema while retriving complete list in a model?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have define a method on mongoose model as follows -

```
PatientSchema.methods.getAge = function(){
    let ageDifMs = (Date.now() - this.dateOfBirth.getTime());
    let ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    let age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    return age;
}
```

It is working fine when I retrieve a single instance of that related model. Now my question when I retrieve multiple instance as follows -

```
const patientList = await Patient.find({})
```

How can I added new key-value pair in JS object where value is generated using method define in model. I can do it using loop but I want to know if there is any optimized way?

UPDATE -
As mentioned by @Milad Raeisi, I use virtuals as follows-

```
PatientSchema.virtual('age').get(function () {
    let temp = new Date(this.dateOfBirth)
    let ageDifMs = (Date.now() - temp.getTime());
    let ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
})
```

Also set `mongoose.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });`

Again it is work perfectly for a single instance but returning null for multiple instance.

I am using code as below to get patient list -

```
const patientList = await Patient.find({})
            .sort({name:1})
            .limit(limit)
            .skip(skipIndex)
            .select(['name', 'gender', 'age'])
            .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have an efficient way, you can do it in an aggregation query or you can store age in some cache and read age from there but normally you can use mongoose virtuals and calculate age in a virtual field.

[check this link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)

Edit:

There is no need to get age from mongoose, because it's a virtual field and not exists on db, and also you need to get dateOfBirth in select in order to mongoose be able to calculate age in virtual field.

try this

```
const patientList = await Patient.find({})
        .sort({name:1})
        .limit(limit)
        .skip(skipIndex)
        .select(['name', 'gender', 'dateOfBirth'])
        .exec();
```

Comment: It is working fine for a single instance but returning null value of age in list.

Comment: How you get age in list?